# Argument handling exception by User Code

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to fetch data from some other site and store.When trying to load the string to XmlDocument, It says me ArgumentException was unhandled by usercode: Illegal characters in the path.

This is the following code.

```
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
   response = request.GetResponse()
        If response.StatusCode = 200 Then
            Dim reader As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim readStream As New System.IO.StreamReader(reader, Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim responseFromServer As String = readStream.ReadToEnd()
            Dim xmld As XmlDocument
            Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList
            xmld = New XmlDocument()

            xmld.Load(responseFromServer) //Error throws here
            nodelist = xmld.GetElementsByTagName("a:data")
            For Each node As XmlElement In nodelist
                If node("a:id").InnerText.Trim = "name" Then 'Next Business Day response (NBD)- General Warranty
                    MsgBox(node("a:name").InnerText.Trim)
                End If
            Next
            MsgBox(readStream)
        End If
```

One of the method I tried:

```
            Dim readStream As New System.IO.StreamReader(reader, Encoding.UTF8)                
            Dim xmld As XmlDocument
            Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList
            xmld = New XmlDocument()

            xmld.Load(readStream) //Error throws here
```

For this method it returns as:
  XmlException was unhandled by usercode
  Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Then tried of different solutions but nothing takes me in the rightway.**I tried with loadxml also**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add the response from server? The errors says about illegal characters

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xmld.LoadXml(responseFromServer)
```

The `.Load` method is expecting a file name.

Comment: Then please say that in your question and then show us the string that you're attempting to load. If you can't do that then we can't answer this question.